# Groupby, iterate and concatenate to text file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My original question was too vague so I am re-doing it. I am VERY new to python and programming, so please be kind. I am trying to take an excel sheet that has Group_Number, Group_Name, Owner of Group as one line, Then putting all the members of the group 'MESSAGING_ID', "NAME", to an individual txt files, named for the group number (for the future to format them into reports and send to the group owners for review).

I managed to get the files created, numbered correctly, and iterate 1 line in the text for the Group_Number, Group_Name, Owner of Group as one line. The problem I am having is adding the multi members to the individual groups. I suspect that the iterate is only reading the one line and skipping the rest, but I am unsure of how to get pandas/python to write the members.

There are 11,000 lines but only 150 groups.

I tried a groupby("Group_Number") but it keeps error-ing

```
from sys import exit
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

##Column Names Set UP
# Create a dataframe from csv
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\GroupRoster05272021.xlsx')

## try to isolate members
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\GroupRoster05272021.xlsx', 
sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="F,G")

#Dynamically write this file as the group number and edit with Group Name, owner, address
file = (r'C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\{}.txt')
df2 = group_number = df.groupby(f'{i}')

##looping the Group_Number and create/write files
##j = group_number.get_group(i)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    with open(file.format(row['Group_Number']), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row['Group_Number']))
        f.write(",  ")
        f.write(str(row['Group_Name']))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(str(row['Process_Owner']))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(str(row['Email_Address']))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("\n")

### I want to append here to add the members(more than one line) to the txt file but the 
####iteration above only 
####reads the first line of everything. I can't get it to write the members fully.
```

Comment: What is the error? | Any sample data to demo "adding the multi members to the individual groups." part ?

Comment: "Series objects are mutable and cannot be hashed" error. Like I said I am a newby and it runs when I comment out the "J' part, I just can't get it to write the group members to the files within my loop. I am sure it is me, as I am very new to programming

Comment: error.. refers to which line? (asked before) any sample data to test with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code and got it to work with my loop thanks for help.

```
from sys import exit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
##Column Names Set UP
dtypes = {
    "Group_Number": "category",
    "Group_Name": "category",
    "Process_Owner": "category",
    "Email_Address": "category",
    "MESSAGING_ID": "category",
    "NAME": "category",
}


# Create a dataframe from csv
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\aross9\Desktop\outFile\GroupRoster05272021.xlsx',
                   dtype=dtypes,
                   usecols=list(dtypes) + ["Group_Number", "Group_Name", "Process_Owner", "Email_Address", "MESSAGING_ID", "NAME"],
#Dynamically write this file as the group number and edit with Group Name, owner, address
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for x, (name, group) in enumerate(df.groupby('Group_Number')):
        group.to_excel('group{}.xlsx'.format(name), index=False)
```